# ServiceStack NuGet update 4.0.22 to 4.0.31 caused errors on deployment

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm hoping not to be to vague here, but I've just done a NuGet update for ServiceStack, updating from version 4.0.22 to 4.0.31, the project compiles fine but once deployed to iis I'm getting this error when I hit the site.

Method 'get_Cookies' in type 'ServiceStack.Host.AspNet.AspNetRequest' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.31.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Wondering if anyone else is having this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A side-effect of ServiceStack converting `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` into a pure PCL dll in **v4.0.30** is that projects that reference interfaces with `System.Net` classes now require an [explicit reference to System.Net](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#breaking-changes).

#### Install Patch for PCL Support with .NET 4.0

From similar [.NET 4.0 Issue with Google OAuth PCL libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=353#c47):

1. Make sure your .NET framework is patched. [Microsoft released patches to .NET 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) to allow Portable Class Libraries to properly find the appropriate runtime (info [KB2468871](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)). If you are seeing the above exception (or something like it), it means you're missing the latest .NET framework patches.
2. Install .NET 4.0 full profile

Comment: I've added those references to the project and I was still getting the same issues. 
To help reduce my coding errors, I created a new hello world servicestack project based on the latest servicestack asp.net empty template, I deployed the project to the server and same issue.
From here, I have a suspicion it may be a .net framework issue. this link is also unsolved [Link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/137), in the trace code I can see .net 4.0 reference. the reason I think it may be then framework is the default template will create .net4.5 project even if you choose .net4.0

Comment: I though I'd chose a .net4.5 project, so I did it again, and on project creation, if you choose 4.0, once created it is 4.5, so I converted it back to 4.0 which did give a warning about the servicestack versions, but it does compile, sorry for all the blurb ,but it seems I still don't have a solution.

Comment: @Ian see updated answer for link to KB2468871 patch.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I believe I've traced it back to not having [KB2468871](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871) installed on some client machines. This causes weird errors such as the one you are seeing. My particular one was this:

```
Method 'GetAsync' in type 'ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Client, Version=4.0.30.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

I tried adding the `System.Net` reference and that didn't clear it up either.

For now, I'm sticking with 4.0.24 (the pre-PCL version) until I can come up with a better solution, since I'm not in control of the client environment. Note that if you are using ClickOnce, you can add this particular update as a prerequisite to the bootstrap installer, but it won't have an effect on already-installed machines, thus the problem here.

Comment: Cheers for that, I've managed to twist my Admin's arm enough to get 4.5 installed tonight, and while that may hide exactly what the issue is, It's a good excuse for me to start using some of the yummy coding stuff in 4.5, so I'm happy. Either way I'll post whether it fixes the problem, I hope so now that I've told him it's his server, I don't really like the taste of humble pie :)

Comment: I got to work this morning and the Admin has upgraded to .net 4.5 which has fixed the problem, obviously the suggestions above to run patch KB2468871 may be the better option for some.