# Method 'get_StatusCode' in type 'ServiceStack.HttpResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I have some services that return json on my site and I'm using Servicestack in order to return custom HttpResults,

This works fine on my local machine and I'm getting the expected result, but when I create a build and then published the site, my services are not working and I receive this message:

Any idea will be great for me,

```
Method 'get_StatusCode' in type 'ServiceStack.HttpResult' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.


[TypeLoadException: Method 'get_StatusCode' in type 'ServiceStack.HttpResult' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.]       
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
```

Answer (score 0):

`TypeLoadException`'s like this are usually indicative that you're using Dirty dlls from different ServiceStack versions together in which case [clearing the NuGet Package Cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet#redownloading-myget-packages) and deleting the NuGet `/packages` folder and re-fetching the latest packages will usually solve it.

However in this case since [HttpResult has had the StatusCode property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/fc191835d97e5b6d89d3cd7a4742793af44eb8c3/src/ServiceStack/HttpResult.cs#L188) for several years it's likely due to the [PCL issue referencing a System.Net Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863800/85785) in which case you will need your project to add an explicit reference to `System.Net` Assembly to resolve it.

Comment: Ty very much mythz I have on the package folder "ServiceStack version 4.0.33.0 and 4.0.34.0", I'll remove all content from the package folder and create a build again,  do you think with that will be enough? ( I'm using only 4.0.34.0 )